# Raise error when setting out of range values

Tags: python, numpy, types, integer-overflow, array-broadcasting

How can one allow checking for out of range values in numpy, when, for example, setting a `uint8` matrix element equal to `-1`? The current behavior just **accepts it silently**, setting the element to `255`. Is there a way to enable an error to be raised during debugging, or can this only be achieved by subclassing numpy arrays? This is a rather frequent phenomenon that is hard to be observed and corrected, particularly when there are multiple operations.

An example:

```
import numpy as np
img = np.zeros((5, 5), dtype=np.uint8)
img[:] = -1
img
```

and the output:

```
array([[255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess manual prechecking is not an option, because you want to rely on the high speed of numpy?

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. You are right. However, there are other operations, which can cause floating point exceptions, and those are taken under consideration,  with their error level handled by `numpy.seterr`  method.

Comment: did you try using NaN instead of -1? But that would really only be a solution to this specific problem

Comment: The only way to avoid illegal values during masking would be to use the `numpa.ma` module, but this is an overkill, it decreases performance and is not globally usable. That is the reason why I do not find the reasoning behind the absence of such debugging flag.

Comment: one way to actually avoid this would be using cython as it enforces strict types. But that’s probably also overkill